# What is the correct way to write the interjection "ha ha?"

Tags: etymology, colloquialisms, interjections

I had a hard time finding the English origin of this interjection and how it technically should be written. I am often ridiculed in written conversations, especially those that are informal, because I might reply to something funny with, "Ha ha ha." It seems as if the accepted way to colloquially spell this is "hahaha."

When asked about it, I actually admitted that the original spelling might have been something like "ha-ha-ha," similar to how "goodbye" seems to have been originally written as "good-bye."

What is the correct way?

Comment: Which “ha ha” do you mean? The one that’s a minor third descending, or the one that’s a perfect fourth ascending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ha%2Bha) has ***“ha ha”***. Normal rules of capitalization, punctuation and the like apply, so a complete interjection might be written “Ha ha ha!”

As an onomatopaeic word, it would be possible to join the individual sounds together to get *hahaha* but this is more suited to less formal environments.

Don’t hyphenate it, because a *ha-ha* is [something rather different](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ha-ha).

Comment: There ***was*** no original spelling. Interjections are outside the conventions of English spelling because they are all sound, no meaning. Identify the sound and you get (some of) the meaning. _hahaha_ is the accepted form among your friends, so if you want to be like your friends (which is the normal reason for learning a new language/dialect/convention), txt like your friends. After all, that's all they're seeing; that's **you**.

Comment: [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haha#Noun) shows a cross-sectional view of a ha-ha or haha and shows both spellings for it, while [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ha-ha) only shows hyphenated form.

Comment: @John Lawler: I don't want to be like my friends. I just wanted a justification for using the spelling I preferred. :)

Comment: You don't need one, then. You can make up your own. _Nihil Obstat_